# Kivy Python Scrollview event misfiring when in a class instantiated multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

In a Kivy/Python program, I have a class which contains a scrollview.  I instantiate this class multiple times.  The scrollview is bound to the on_scroll_stop event.  My desired outcome is that the on_scroll_stop event will only fire within the instantiated class to which it belongs, but it seems that the event fires across all of the instantiated classes.  Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior?  Working sample below.  In this example the "Left" section shows the issue most often, however the error is seen in the right section once you scroll up at the top or scroll down once reaching the bottom.  To recreate scroll only one side, preferably the "Left" side. In my actual code which is far more complex the issue is much more prevalent.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class DisplaySection(Widget):

    def CreateSection(self):

        self.display_panel_main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.elements_layout = FloatLayout(size_hint_y=None)

        self.sv = ScrollView()
        self.sv.bind(on_scroll_stop=self.on_scrolling_stop)
        self.sv.add_widget(self.elements_layout)

        self.display_panel_main_layout.add_widget(self.sv)

        return self.display_panel_main_layout


    def LoadElements(self,section_name):

        self.section_name = section_name

        number_of_elemements = 100
        element_hieght = 40
        layout_height = number_of_elemements * element_hieght

        self.elements_layout.height = layout_height

        xcord = 0

        for x in range(number_of_elemements):
            ycord = self.elements_layout.height - element_hieght*x
            name = Label(text='Name' + str(x),size_hint_y=None, height=40,pos=(xcord,ycord))
            self.elements_layout.add_widget(name)

    def on_scrolling_stop(self, sv, value):
        #print(sv,value)
        print('I am',self.section_name)


class testscrollapp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        main_layout = BoxLayout()

        section_names = ['Left','Right']

        for x, section_name in enumerate(section_names):
            section_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

            btn = Button(text=section_name,size_hint=(1,None))
            section_layout.add_widget(btn)
            # instantiate the class containing the scroll view
            scroll_layout = DisplaySection()
            scr = scroll_layout.CreateSection()

            section_layout.add_widget(scr)

            scroll_layout.LoadElements(section_name)
            
            main_layout.add_widget(section_layout)
            
        return main_layout

testscrollapp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_scroll_stop` event is dispatched just like touch events, so any `ScrollView` instance that subscribes to `on_scroll_stop` will get all the `on_scroll_stop` events. And just like a touch event, the subscribing `ScrollView` instance must determine which of the events it is interested in, and ignore the rest. Since the `value` argument to your `on_scrolling_stop` is the `MouseMotionEvent`, you can do a `collide_point()` test to determine if the scroll event is within the `ScrollView`:

```
def on_scrolling_stop(self, sv, value):
    if sv.collide_point(*value.pos):
        print('\tI am',self.section_name)
```